# Chrome: Fixed background is displayed as it wasn't fixed

Tags: html, css, webkit

i can't understand why my fixed background starts to be as it wasn't fixed some times.

This is very particular case, and i know how to fix it.

You can remove:

`.row2` `position:relative`

or

`row1` `div` `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

But i don't understand why this problem happens, how `position:relative` or `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden` could affect this behavior.

I think this question can attract someone interest.

Here is example: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q54eV/2/)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <title>Theme Framework</title>
    <style>
        .row1 {
            height:45px;
        }
        .row1 div {
            height:47px;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        }
        .row2 {
            position: relative;
            height:500px;
            background-image:url(http://www.hdwallpapers.in/download/uphill_road-1024x768.jpg);
            background-position: 50% 23px;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size:cover;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row1">
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: image seems to be fixed in the background, what way are you expecting it to behave on first load???

Answer (score 1):

In this case it looks like it looks like the `backface-visibility` was interfering with the `background-attachment`. The key here is that the element with `backface-visibility` is taller than it's containing element. Which means it extends below `row1`. Adding `overflow:hidden` to `row1` fixes the issue.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q54eV/5/)**

CSS:

```
  .row1 {
    height:45px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

As far as what is actually happening here. It's my guess (still looking for the complete answer) that since the element with `backface-visibility` is overlapping and overwriting the backgrond fixed style. Probably an error with the rendering engine.

Comment: Yep, i have noticed that too. That caused only when element with backface property contain another element, which height is more than it's parent height. 

It seems, we have to ask chrome devs